# %k not returning kernel number in udev rule

Tags: kernel, udev

[This page](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) (revised dozens of times over a few years. Awesome!) that provides a-to-z of `udev` says:

> `%k` evaluates to the kernel name for the device, e.g. "sda3" for a device that would (by default) appear at `/dev/sda3`. `%n` evaluates to the kernel number for the device (the partition number for storage devices), e.g. "3" for `/dev/sda3`.

But for me `%k` returns `sda` in the example above for my dongle.

Portion of the `udev` rule affecting I think is (it gets installed via [this deb](http://www.codemeter.de/downloads/files/cm6_60/lin/codemeter-lite_6.60.2869.500_amd64.deb) from [this page](http://codemeter.com/us/service/downloads_linux.html), and it requires proprietary dongle btw):

```
LABEL="codemeter_mount"
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"
ENV{ID_FS_UUID}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_UUID}"  
#ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="", ENV{dir_name}="cm-%k"
ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="", ENV{dir_name}="cm-pickone"                                     # Use static path. Multiple dongles are not intended to be used, so this should be ok.
RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/CodeMeter/%E{dir_name}"
RUN+="/bin/mount /dev/%k /media/CodeMeter/%E{dir_name} -o umask=0000,uid=1,gid=1"
```

Above rule expects to mount on e.g. `/dev/sdb1` but because of the mentioned issue, `/dev/%k` becomes a path to the disk, not partition thus `mount` fails (a quick hack I found is to use `%k%n`).

Am I misunderstanding anything?

As below I'm on Ubuntu Xenial but on I see the same on Trusty.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
$ apt-cache policy udev
udev:
  Installed: 229-4ubuntu21
  Candidate: 229-4ubuntu21
  Version table:
 *** 229-4ubuntu21 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     229-4ubuntu10 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     229-4ubuntu4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Use `%N` for the device node (`sda3`), or `ENV{DEVNAME}` (`/dev/sda3`).  See bottom of `man 7 udev` for current details about udev substitutions.  (udev follows the [CADT](https://www.jwz.org/doc/cadt.html) development model).    Also run `udevadm info /dev/sda3` for a list of everything knows about the device.